# Laravel polymorphic relationship

Tags: laravel-4, polymorphic-associations

I have different Database tables and below is the DB Diagram.
I am trying to make a many to many polymorphic relationship, but no luck, Please guide me that what i need to do, means where i need to add which type relationship/code?

[image]

Comment: Do you a quiz to morphBy a course, a chapter or a lessen?

Comment: @blablabla I didn't understand your question ? actually i am new to laravel.
What I want, to assign the quiz to a course, chapter or lesson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Course Model

```
class Course extends Eloquent {

    public function quizzes()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('Quiz', 'quizzable');
    }

}
```

Chapter Model

```
class Chapter extends Eloquent {

    public function quizzes()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('Quiz', 'quizzable');
    }

}
```

Lesson Model

```
class Lesson extends Eloquent {

    public function quizzes()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('Quiz', 'quizzable');
    }

}
```

Quiz Model

```
class Quiz extends Eloquent {

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('Course', 'quizzable');
    }

    public function chapters()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('Chapter', 'quizzable');
    }

    public function lessons()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('Lesson', 'quizzable');
    }

}
```

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

I would change the quizzes_assigned table to:

```
Table name: quizzables
    quiz_id - integer
    quizzable_id - integer
    quizzable_type - string
```